# Change date format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in a file using shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, date, unix, scripting

I have a source file with 18 columns in which columns 10 , 11 and 15 are in the format dd/mm/yyyy and all these needs to be converted to yyyy-mm-dd and written to target file along with other columns.
I am aware of date formatting functions on Variables but do not know how to apply the same on few columns in a file.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t have a machine available to test, but consider using `awk` with a little function since you are doing the same thing 3 times. It will look something like this:

```
awk ‘
   function dodate(in){
      split(in,/\//,a)   # split existing date into elements of array “a”
      return a[3] “-“ a[2] “-“ a[1]
   }

   { $10=dodate($10); $11=dodate($11); $15=dodate($15); print }’ yourFile
```

Reference for awk [functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Function-Example.htmlhttp://), and [split](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gawk/html_node/String-Functions.html).

If the fields on each line are separated by commas, tell `awk` that with:

```
awk -F, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use command `awk` to solve it.

As you have 3 cols contain date (col 10, 11, 15), here I assume a sample string which field seperator is `|`, col contains date is the 4th col

```
aa|bb|cc|29/09/2017|dd|ee|ff
```

use [String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to extract date, then format it with [getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html) to format it to expected syntax.

command is

```
echo 'aa|bb|cc|2017-09-29|dd|ee|ff' | awk -F\| 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{$4=gensub(/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})/,"\\3\\2\\1","g",$4); "date --date=\""$4"\" +\"%F\"" | getline a; $4=a; print $0}'
```

output is

```
aa|bb|cc|2017-09-29|dd|ee|ff
```

Hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `dateutils` package installed, you can use `dateutils.dconv`

```
cat file | dateutils.dconv -S -i "%d/%m/%Y"
```

- `-i` specify input date format
- `-S` sed mode, process only the matched string and copy the rest

Input File

```
aa|bb|cc|29/09/2017|dd|ee|ff|02/10/2017|gg
```

Output

```
aa|bb|cc|2017-09-29|dd|ee|ff|2017-10-02|gg
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the date command:

```
    while read fmtDate
      do
        date -d ${fmtDate} "+%Y-%m-%d"
     done
```

Comment: The OP has three dates on each line of a file. The fields on the line are probably separatedby commas and the dates are in fields 10, 11 and 15. Your code doesn’t appear to address that.